# Best stack for video streaming site

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, wowza

I am building a video streaming service and I am weighing the options for the technology to use. Some options I have considered are HTML5+ Node.js, Wowza. 
I am looking for a stack that would be efficient, scalable and offer low latency in streaming. I also want it to be secure as some of the videos might be paid. 
What stack would you advise ?